# Cors policy blocking JSON request

Tags: json, api, cors

Basically, my issue is that while I try to run a function that calls an API, I get a CORS policy issue. I've found out that it seems to exist on some endpoints, yet not on others. I know it's not an issue in my code, I just feel like I'm missing something. I've been looking for an answer but often these include API requests from other languages and solutions could not be applied in *my* scenario. Here's my code:
When running this code, I get an error with CORS policy issues. Are there any additional headers I need add in my API request that I am missing? I couldn't understand the docs so im looking for help here. Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
   
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      body {
        background-color: #313131;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form class="form-inline" id="form" onsubmit="return false; ">
      <!--User inputs username in form-->
      <input
        class="form-control mr-sm-2"
        type="text"
        id="myText"
        placeholder="Enter a Username"
        class="searchTerm"
        aria-label="Search"
      />
      <!--Submit form button + SVG search I-->
      <button
        type="submit"
        class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0"
        onclick="myFunction()"
        class="searchButton"
      >
        <!--SVG search incon-->
        <svg style="width: 24px; height: 24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
          <path
            fill="currentColor"
            d="M9.5,3A6.5,6.5 0 0,1 16,9.5C16,11.11 15.41,12.59 14.44,13.73L14.71,14H15.5L20.5,19L19,20.5L14,15.5V14.71L13.73,14.44C12.59,15.41 11.11,16 9.5,16A6.5,6.5 0 0,1 3,9.5A6.5,6.5 0 0,1 9.5,3M9.5,5C7,5 5,7 5,9.5C5,12 7,14 9.5,14C12,14 14,12 14,9.5C14,7 12,5 9.5,5Z"
          />
        </svg>
      </button>
    </form>
    <script>
      function myFunction() {
        var username = document.getElementById('myText').value;
        var url =
          'http://api.quran.com/api/v3/search?q=' +
          username +
          '&size=20&page=0&language=ar';
        $.getJSON({
          url: url,
          success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
          },
        });
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any solutions that can help me access the data will be pleasantly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please share the exact error you’re receiving? We’d need it to point you in the right direction.

Comment: Sorry for the late response:

Comment: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://api.quran.com/api/v3/search?q=pig&size=20&page=0&language=ar' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the docs, you may need to specify a few extra options in your request. Try this.

```
var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "http://api.quran.com/api/v3/search?q=" + username + "&size=20&page=0&language=ar",
  "method": "GET",
  "headers": {},
  "data": "{}"
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
```